# removeClass isn't working while addClass in the same condition is working

Tags: jquery

I have some jQuery code which should remove a class and add another class when a part of an URL is equal to an URL in `a href`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = location.pathname;
    var urlSplit = url.split('/');
    var urlFull = urlSplit[1] + '/' + urlSplit[2];
    $(".submenumoe>li").each(function() {
        var navHref = $(this).find("a").attr("href");

        $(".submenu li a").addClass('submenu-empty'); 

        if (navHref.indexOf(urlFull) > -1) {                    
            $(this).find("a").removeClass('submenu-empty'); 
            $(this).find("a").addClass('submenu-on');                   
        } else {
            // some code
        }   
    });
});
```

The class "submenu-on" is added to the menu item where navHref.indexOf(urlFull) > -1 but the class "submenu-empty" isn't deleted?

Comment: What does the console say when you add `console.log(navHref.indexOf(urlFull))` just before the if statement?

Comment: The logic works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/fkzwc3Lo/. The issue must therefore be with how you dissect the URL. Check the values of `urlFull` and `navHref `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code

```
 $(".submenu li a").addClass('submenu-empty');
```

will add the class again to every a tag as it is added inside the loop even if the condition is true.

Below code should work

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = location.pathname;
    var urlSplit = url.split('/');
    var urlFull = urlSplit[1] + '/' + urlSplit[2];
    $(".submenumoe > li").each(function() {
        var navHref = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
        if (navHref.indexOf(urlFull) > -1) {                     
            $(this).find("a").addClass('submenu-on');                   
        } else {
            $(this).find("a").addClass('submenu-empty');
        }   
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

Please check if it helps you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = "example.com/question/abc/xyz";
    var urlSplit = url.split('/');
    var urlFull = urlSplit[1] + '/' + urlSplit[2];
    $(".submenumoe > li").each(function() {
        var navHref = $(this).find("a");
        if (navHref.attr("href").indexOf(urlFull) > -1) {                    
            navHref.removeClass('submenu-empty').addClass('submenu-on'); 
        } else {
            navHref.addClass('submenu-empty').removeClass('submenu-on'); 
        }   
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="submenumoe">
  <li>
    <a href="question/abc">Demo</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="question/pqr">Demo 2</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```